# How to execute a scheduled function in Laravel, manually?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm a bit lost in translation, English is not my primary language, so I might not be asking exactly what I mean, I'm sorry

This is my problem: I have a scheduled task that works perfectly, but all the logic is inside the `function()` in the `$schedule->call()`, I mean:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
  $schedule->call(function () {
    //
    // All my code goes here, around 25 lines, it calls an external API
    // and then stores the data on the database, it repeats every day at
    // 0700, timezone is not very relevant
    //
  })->dailyAt('07:00');
}
```

I want to do two things:

1. How can I run the task "now", I mean by an Artisan command or something like that
2. How can I run the tasks (the comments) on a `seeder`, one option would be to repeat the code, but I don't want to. Do I have to create an invokable controller? I think that might work but I'm not sure if that's the correct way to do it.

I know this looks quite basic, but I really don't know where to place the code so its executable both from the seeder and the scheduler, or even when clicking a button ‍♂️ do I have to create a helper maybe?

Comment: why don't you try this https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler-locally

Comment: Yeah... it works...I created an invokable object, and it is invoked by the scheduler, now what I would like to do, is to call that code inside the DatabaseSeeder

Comment: you could make an artisan command which you could call via the CLI, the scheduler and your "seeder"

Comment: for locally running command you can use everyMinute() instead of daliyAt() - ofcourse you can change it while uploading on server. 
other method is  to use laravel homestead which provide you same environment as liver server. 
as far as use of same code is concern. You can create global function and use it anywhere in the system

Answer (score 4):

for 1 use `php artisan schedule:test` Enter, and bring to you list of all schedules select a schedule then Enter.

for 2 use `\Artisan::call('your command');`

Answer (score 0):

1. Move the logic to invokable class(which you have already done as it seems from OP comments). You can also create Helper Class instead if that helps.

> Off-topic: There is no restriction or rule on where you put your code,
> just think from a future developer's point-of-view and you should be
> fine. You can always tweak later.

2. [Create artisan command](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/artisan#writing-commands) and call invokable/helper class from there.
3. In seeder, [call Artisan command programmatically](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands).

Answer (score 0):

1. To run all schedulers you can use **php artisan schedule:run**, it will run given a scheduled command defined in App\Console\Kernel.
2. I didn't understand your second question can you explain?